# Python django - user object not found

Tags: python, django

I have this class in views.py

```
class getUserData:
    def get(self, data):
        try:
            if self.user.username:
                user = UserData.objects.get(Username=self.user.username)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            print("Error!")
```

and..

```
def CheckUserData(request):
    if not getUserData().get('ddd') 
      dsada
```

On PyCharm - windows - its all ok. On Ubuntu show me error: getUserData instance has no attribute 'user'

Please help

Comment: You're not using `data` in `get`. Is it intentional? Note that your code seems a bit unusual overall, you might want to explain what you're trying to do in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

The whole piece of code is unnecessary. `self.user` is *already* an instance of User. There's absolutely no point getting that user's username and using that to query the User model again: you'd just get back the exact same data you started with.

Just use `self.user` directly.

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
from django.views import generic
class GetUserData(generic.View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        if user.username:
            myuser = UserData.objects.filter(username=user.username)
            if myuser:
                print 'coo'
            else:
                print 'nope'
```

If the data is coming from Get request then do this:

```
get_data = self.request.GET  # Parse get set after then blammo
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you make this, but for normal function, not get? I don't understand args, kwargs.. I must use: GetUserData.getData("dsa") - Your code is not work - the same problem.